# Force MicroService to await until RabbitMQ publishes a message , using Cote

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, microservices, cote

I have a an API-GATEWAY MicroService that manages the entire show , and one of the services is called QueueService.

**Here is the API-Gateway**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cote = require('cote')
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors());


app.post('/queue-msg', async (req, res, next) => {
    let { from, to } = req.body;
    const payload = {
        from, to
    }
    const queue = await queueRequester.send({ type: 'create-queue-message', payload })
    res.status(200).send({ "message-sent": true, queue });
});
```

**This is thq QueueService :**

```
const cote = require('cote')
const queueProducer = require('./utils/queueProducer');
const queueName = 'pathfinderqueue';
const queueResponder = new cote.Responder({ name: 'queue responder', key: 'deliveries' })
queueResponder.on('*', req => req.type && console.log(req))

const deliveries = []
let idCounter = 0

queueResponder.on('create-queue-message', req => {

    async function makeRequest() {
        console.log('Got a message from API-GATEWAY!');
        let { payload } = req;  // get From & To
        queueProducer.publishToQueue(queueName, payload); // Publish to Rabbit
        const queue = { id: idCounter++, status: 'pending' } // Set the ID 
        deliveries.push(queue)
        return Promise.resolve(queue)
    }

    const response = makeRequest();
    return response;
})
```

However every time that API-Gateway publishes a message from the React client to the QueueService , the QueueService doesn't awaits in the `on` event , and sends back a

```
"message-sent": true
```

to the client.

How can we force QueueService to await ?